# Return user details after they have logged in

Tags: c#

the code below works ok, just one issue, the code confirms if user logged in is Admin or not i.e. the code checks if the user name is within the AspNetUser table and returns a Boolean true or false.
But I also need the user GarageID to be returned, the GarageID field is held within the AspNetUser table any ideas how to do this?

```
 private bool IsUserAdmin()
    {
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity = Context.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
        //Debug.WriteLine(identity.Name);

        string loginName = identity.Name;
        //Debug.WriteLine(loginName);

        TyrescannerWebApp.IdentityModel.tyrescannerdatabaseEntities dbcontext = new TyrescannerWebApp.IdentityModel.tyrescannerdatabaseEntities();

        return content.AdminUsers.Any(a => a.LoginName == loginName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the role provider to determine if the user is in the current role.

```cs
if (System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(loginName, "Admin"))
{
    //Do something
}
else
{
    //Display unauthorized message
}
```

Comment: Hi, code works ok now just one issue,  the code confirms if user logged in is Admin or not i.e. the code checks if the user name is within the AspNetUser table and returns a Boolean true or false.
But I also need the user GarageID to be returned, the GarageID is held within the AspNetUser table any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Sorry I misread the question.  Is the GarageID a FK to another entity?  It appears you're using a flavor of EF so you would do
    dbcontext.AdminUsers.Include(a => a.Garage).Any(a => a.LoginName == loginName);

Comment: If it's not a related entity and is just a simple type, then there should be a property on your user class that exposes it.  Otherwise, there isn't a great way to do it without going straight to the DB.

Comment: The GarageID is expose but receiving the following error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type" at this piece of code dbcontext.AdminUsers.Include(a => a.Garage)

Comment: Try adding

   using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: Can you post the class for your user also